# AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI Installation Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pyenv

Need some help.

I am in the process of installing AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI and have followed the instructions on the official [repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup) but have encountered the following error:

```
$ ./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/bundled_installer

==============================================
I. Installing Python
==============================================

*************************************************************
1. Determining whether pyenv is already installed and in PATH
*************************************************************
    - pyenv was not found in PATH.

*********************************************************
2. Determining whether pyenv should be cloned from GitHub
*********************************************************
    - pyenv git repository already cloned to /c/Users/HGG/.pyenv-repository. Won't attempt to clone again.

*******************************************
3. Temporarily export necessary pyenv paths
*******************************************

****************************************************************************
4. Checking whether Python can be downloaded (through curl, wget, or aria2c)
****************************************************************************

************************************************************
5. Installing Python 3.7.2. This step may take a few minutes
************************************************************
/c/Users/HGG/.pyenv-repository/bin/pyenv: line 1: ../libexec/pyenv: No such file or directory
   Exiting due to failure
```

I am using Bash and has tried uninstalling Python and pip to no avail.
The file `../libexec/pyenv` can be found manually.

Need some help guys.

Thanks.

Comment: `brew install pyenv`?

Comment: Seems like you have not configured the path properly. Can you verify if pyenev is installed and configured properly

Comment: @ChatterOne, 'brew install pyenv' don't seem to work on GitBash. Is there an equivalent command?

Comment: @Harshit Garg, sorry I don't know Python. Do I need to install Python, pip and pyenv separate?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:
I forgot to install Python for All users in my Window (that's why cmd > python --version returned nothing) and also need to check environment variable is set correctly.

Refer https://anthonydebarros.com/2018/06/21/setting-up-python-in-windows-10/